# How to unlink a copied page on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder, document-set, hyperlink

I needed to seperat a page on my sharepoint, so i made a copy of the page. So as to keep the look and feel the same. I now want to make changes to the folders in the duplciate site. How do i do that without it channging folders in the oringal page? Every time i make a change in the folder on the duplicate page, it changes it on the oringal page. The pages seem to be linked, how do i change that and set up a document libary just for the new content

Answer (score 0):

Since the copy page and the original page use the same document web part, the changes on the copy page will be synchronized to the original page.

You could use save document as a template, then create a new document library, use new document library in the copy page.

Reference:

[5 ways to store and reuse document templates in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/5-ways-to-store-and-reuse-document-templates-in-sharepoint)